# Unity Character Controller pushing another Character Controller (i have script)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have stumbled across a problem. I have modified an impact script which I found here in the forums that makes the player push away another player with use of box colliders as triggers. The problem is, the impact is rather inconsistent. The direction sometimes does not make sense (player goes the other direction when pushed) and the force varies from very strong to very light and I don't really know what makes it do that. This is the code I attached to the game objects:

```
void FixedUpdate () {
   //p2 being player 2 character controller
    if (impact.magnitude > 0.2f)
        p2.Move (impact * Time.deltaTime);

    impact = Vector3.Lerp (impact, Vector3.zero, 5 * Time.deltaTime);
    pos = (p2.GetComponent<Transform> ().transform.position - transform.position);
}

//adds impact force
public void AddImpact(Vector3 dir, float force)
{
    dir.Normalize ();
    if (dir.y < 0)
        dir.y = -dir.y;

    if (dir.y > 0)
        dir.y = 0;

    impact += dir.normalized * force / mass;
}

public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    AddImpact (pos, 20);
}
```

I also activate this code in time with the animation using (.enabled) whenever the animation is playing. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this? I can't seem to after two days of staring at the code analyzing. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: is it intended that dir.y always ends up zero in `AddImpact()`? I might be mistaken, but in the current code if dir.y is negative, you switch the sign so it will be zero or positive, and then if it is greater zero, it ends up zero. so same as `dir.y = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have an issue in your `AddImpact()` method.

Your current code will first normalize the `dir`, zero out `dir.y`, then calculate a force using `dir` and add it to `impact`. However, when you evaluate `dir.normalized * force / mass` in the last line, the magnitude of `dir` is not guaranteed to be 1 - it is in the range of [0,1], which means the magnitude of the vector you add to `impact` varies anywhere in the range of [0, force / mass]. This is why your force varies in strength so wildly.

The error is in your logic - when you normalize `dir`, you're normalizing the vector with the y-value still at a potentially non-zero value. When you effectively set `dir.y = 0`, that causes the magnitude of `dir` to drop an unknown amount, because you've shortened the vector by removing one of its dimensions.

I'd suggest revising your method to the following:

```
public void AddImpact(Vector3 dir, float force)
{
    dir.y = 0;
    dir.Normalize ();
    impact += dir.normalized * force / mass;
}
```

By normalizing the vector only after setting the `dir.y = 0`, the magnitude of `dir` is now guaranteed to be 1 when used in the force calculation.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.